# How do I setup Chained fast backend, Varnish, APCu and Redis cache bins in settings.php?

Tags: 7, caching

On a Debian Jessie server (`Nginx, PHP 5.6, Zend Opcache`), I installed Apcu, Redis, Varnish. I also installed [APCu](https://www.drupal.org/project/apcu), [Chained fast backend](https://www.drupal.org/project/chained_fast), [Redis](https://www.drupal.org/project/redis) and [Varnish](https://www.drupal.org/project/varnish) modules.

In order to make these caching backends play together with Drupal 7, **what is the correct backend for each cache bin**?

---

The documentation says :

> Because chained_fast backend will mark all the cache entries in a bin as out-dated for each write to a bin, it is best suited to bins with fewer changes.

**How do I take care of that recommendation ?** Is that correct to put APCu as `$conf['chained_fast']['fast_backend']` or is Redis faster ? Between the 20 and more tables, how can I estimate which cache bin should be set to Redis or APCu? Last, shall I only set `cache_page` for Varnish or is `cache_panels` a good candidate also for Varnish if all my pages are built with panels?

At the moment this is my `settings.php` cache part:

```
//Cache backends
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/apcu/apcu.cache.inc';
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/chained_fast/chained_fast.cache.inc';
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/varnish/varnish.cache.inc';
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/redis/redis.autoload.inc';

// Chained fast settings
$conf['chained_fast']['fast_backend'] = 'DrupalAPCuCache';
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'ChainedFastBackend';

// Related Varnish settings
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$conf['cache'] = 1;
$conf['block_cache'] = 1;
$conf['cache_lifetime'] = 0;
$conf['page_cache_maximum_age'] = 86400;
$conf['reverse_proxy_header'] = 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR';
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array('127.0.0.1');
$conf['omit_vary_cookie'] = TRUE;
$conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE; // Don't bootstrap the database when serving pages from the cache.

// Redis settings
$conf['redis_client_interface'] = 'PhpRedis';
$conf['redis_client_host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$conf['lock_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/redis/redis.lock.inc';
$conf['path_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/redis/redis.path.inc';

// Cache bins configuration
$conf['cache_prefix'] = 'vts'; // Unique prefix for each site
$conf['cache_class_cache_entity_node'] = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_entity_user'] = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_page'] = 'VarnishCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_panels'] = 'VarnishCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';  // The 'cache_form' bin must be assigned to non-volatile storage.
```

Comment: To answer the question as it is, we would end up repeating what the documentation for the modules implementing cache back-ends would say. Is there anything in particular that you don't understand? Keep in mind that we cannot answer to "How do I get a performance gain?" as that is too broad.

Comment: There's one for each cache bin, named the same as the bin. Look for tables with names starting `cache_`. Each of those is an answer. Do note that only memcache and apcu are applicable to what you're asking as there are implementations written specifically for Drupal's cache system. Varnish is a different kind of cache and opcache is irrelevant here

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Clive, you said  _only memcache and apcu are applicable to what you're asking_ . What about Redis then ? I edited the question.

Comment: Yep redis is also commonly used as a cache backend, its blazingly fast but not as nice to interface with as, e.g., mongo (not that mongo is used as a cache backend usually, nor redis as a database, though it's possible, but they're often mentioned in the same breath). Use the Drupal integration module and that won't concern you of course

Comment: What's the point of using all possible cache backends that ever existed in the universe together ?